# What would an Earth-like planet with a mostly stable ring be like?

Tags: planets, asteroids, tides, planetary-rings

I recently watched a video talking about what would happen if our moon was on a collision course with the Earth and they described it being ripped apart by Earth's gravity. This made me want to re-examine one of the planets in my setting as it was intended to be a ringed Earth-like planet.

In my setting, there is a planet that is supposed to be the center of the mining industry for its region due to the dense mineral rich rings around it. Scientists speculate that a mineral rich rogue planetoid or what could have been its second moon got pulled into a decaying orbit and was broken apart once it reached the Roche limit, forming a ring. This happened so long ago that most of the asteroids that had a decaying orbit would have fallen long before this planet was discovered by humanity, so the ring is meant to be mostly stable by this time.

It's also believed that the asteroids that fell out of the ring early in its formation had stunted evolution of the planet's local wildlife with regular mass extinction events caused by those early asteroids falling from the ring. I might take this a step further and say that the event caused an extinction of all complex life and left the planet ideal for terraforming.

I haven't quite settled on whether or not the planet has a moon as well as a ring or if it's just going to have the ring, so some of my questions relate to both.

What would the ring look like from the surface at different latitudes? Would there be regions where you couldn't see it at all? How would the presence of the ring versus a moon affect the tides? Or would there be none? Or would the presence of the ring cancel out or lessen the tidal effects of a moon? If the ring had sufficient mass to it, would it be able to produce a magnetosphere in place of a moon?

Would having a moon or small planet break up in the Roche limit have any effect on the terrain of the planet beyond craters from meteors that fall from the newly formed belt?

Comment: Planetary rings aren't stable formations, lasting anywhere around 10-500 million years, depending on size among other things. Saturn's magnificent rings will likely dissipate in the next few hundred million years. A ring formation tens of millions of years old being stumbled upon isn't unlikely in my opinion. (Also, there are a lot of questions here, some of which I believe may already have answers on this site.)

Comment: I did say *mostly* stable. I figured it would be stable enough that the planet wasn't considered to be that much more dangerous than any other planet, even if there was a region directly below the ring that was uninhabitable.

Comment: @Arvex could you put a single question please. I read 8 question marks in your text. And don't forget to check if it has been answered already.. see  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=EARTH+PLANET+RINGS